# Is there any way to write system independent MVC applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cross-platform

For the last two days, I tried running the MVC4 sample internet application (the application created when inside VisualStudio 2010 we go to: File->New->MVC4 webApllication->Internet application (with Razor)) on Mono, in order to check whether I can use Linux to host any real MVC app.

At first - I tried running it with Xamarian Studio and .NET - no problems there: it shows, the startup page, I can register, and login -> Great.

Then I simply switched from .NET to Mono, and all hell broke loose.

1. First it complains that log4net is not found -> installing newest log4net fixed that problem, but why was it complaining in the first place??
2. Then, there is some error with EntityFramework -> updating EF fixed this as well but, again - why wasn't it working?
3. Then I saw start-up page but attempt to register thrown:

   System.MissingMemberException The type being lazily initialized does not have a public, parameterless constructor.

When I refreshed the page, above error was gone but I got another when I try to register:

System.InvalidOperationException
    To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".

I gave up :/

According to this:

http://mono-project.com/Compatibility

MVC4 is compatible as far as asynchronic controllers are not used... so the question is - am I doing something wrong here or is Mono compatibility one big lie?

Allow me to add, that by compatibility, I mean: using THE SAME code, without changing anything (this is how it works in Java or QT).

Thanks in advance for your opinions.

Best regards.

Comment: Try to use titles like, ".NET to Mono portability issues" or something like that. I think the current title is vague and seems to communicate something totally different.

Comment: BTW, Xamarin should have never claimed "code once, run..." as it at th very beginning tries to avoid the Java style failures. I don't know who gives you that information, but he/she must be misleading.

Comment: @LexLi:

Just go to Xamarin.com:

"With Xamarin, you write your apps entirely in C#, sharing the
same code on iOS, Android, Windows and Mac."

For me "sharing the same code" means "code once, run everywhere". Also compatibility matrix on mono site claims "MVC4 should work, with the exception of asynchronic controllers", so for me, that means: it should work out of the box.

Perhaps Mono should change it statement to something like: "MVC4 should work, but you will probably have to port at least some of your code, and some standard functionality that is provided by MS dll's may not work".

Comment: Well, that's your own interpretation, and of course not the official statement from Xamarin. Besides, *Mono is an open source project, not a commercial product from Xamarin*. So what is said for Xamarin's stuffs, does not automatically apply to Mono. Then for an open source project like Mono, you'd better understand "should work" as "it should work but you need to hack". "Out of the box" is rarely a situation you can assume in open source world. Yes, if Mono guys can update their Wiki in your style it probably avoids confusion better.

Answer (score 2):

For your point# 1 and 2 about why log4net and EntityFramework were causing problems, I would think that there are different assemblies for the two frameworks (.NET and Mono). That would be the case to take advantage of the framework features and the way that .NET and Mono are constructed and are optimized for.

For the 3rd point, sounds like SimpleMembership is not recognized by mono. Try this: http://goo.gl/hPnzjV

Before giving up, I would message the mono team/post on community forum... I've heard that they are quite responsive. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for my late response - I will try some more tests later this week. But it is hard to consider Mono for any REAL project, when simplest project fails to run :/ also, if I have to use different code for Mono and .NET, them what's the point of Xamarian campaign "Code once run on bla bla bla"?

Comment: I think Lex Li responded to your point of "Code once run on... " interpretation pretty well. Besides, you are still able to reuse a lot of code, as long as you use different versions of the library for each framework. Much better than learning C# and Objective C and Java and... you get the point. It's only difficult until you get a hang of it, which I agree takes some digging in the beginning but not as much as it would to learn new technologies and languages I would guess :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not from the Mono team, but below are my experience and my observation on how to migrate to Mono from .NET and why something breaks.

- Microsoft does not build ASP.NET MVC or EF to support Mono. Thus, the original assemblies from Microsoft (which is copied locally in VS) won't work as you wished on Mono. Normally Mono ships in GAC the corresponding patched assemblies (with the same names), so use `sudo find / | grep name_of_assembly` to first check which assemblies are already there in GAC, and remove them from your deployment folder on Mono/Linux. We do see Microsoft and Xamarin collaborate on the compatibility side, but it takes time for them to finish all the work.
- Don't use Xamarin Studio on Windows to test things out. No, that's not reliable as it still uses .NET. You need to use MonoDevelop on Linux.

Now for your questions, 1 and 2 are obvious. Mono ships with a version of log4net in GAC, but it's not the latest. So using your own copy is preferred if you like. EF 6 is the first open source release from Microsoft, so using the latest should give you less issues on Mono.

For 3, I think you copied Microsoft's MVC 4 assemblies to Mono/Linux. Please remove the ones that need patching, and then use Mono's ones in GAC.

Don't expect Java or Qt level of compatibility today, as Java spends many years to get to that level. You are just too lucky to see Java's prime time, and .NET/Mono's is just coming.

Comment: Sorry for late response, and thanks for the info, that would explain a thing or two... - I will try Your suggestions later this week. While I understand Mono is not 100% compatible... Xamarian advertisements, claim: "Code once, run on bla bla bla" are... I don't even know how to call them. Also for some weird reason - whether I try to create empty Razor project inside Monodevelop/Xamarian studio, there are dll's missing - so one have to struggle from the beginning to test simple MVC4 application... :/

Comment: Xamarin's statement is correct for BCL where the compatibility is much better. Microsoft seems to start to share test suites with them to help increase compatibility. But this is an on-going process and focus on mobile platforms. ASP.NET is a huge framework which is even more difficult to work on, so I think we still need to wait, or we can help it out.